# In how many ways can 'i' Indian, 'j' chinese, 'k' mexicans, 'l' americans and 'm' canadians be arranged in groups?

Tags: combinatorics

So, this problem has been giving me and my computer some really hard time for over a week now. Whole question is basicly this:

-There is a group of people consisting of "i Indian, j chinese, k mexicans, l americans and m canadians".

-They need to be divided to smaller groups (1 <= size of smaller group <= (i+j+k+l+m))

-If there are two or more same nationalities in one group, there must be at least one another nationality too.

--> In how many ways can these (i+j+k+l+m) people be divided to smaller groups?

Lastly I have tried to solve this in matlab by creating 5 x (i+j+k+l+m) matrix that would go through all possibilitis one by one and checking if this fills given conditions. This way presented every row is one smaller group and whole matrix, if it fills the conditions, is one solution to given problem. Conditions are:

-Every column has total count of people as given in instrucions. For example first column has 8 people if there were 8 indians to be divided in groups.

-First row can not contain zeros only. (To prevent duplicates.)

-Single row can not have only one value, greater than or equal to 2. ("If there are two or more same nationalities in one group, there must be at least one another nationality too.")

If matrix fits to these conditions, program counts its possible combinations (different, identifiable people).
Difficulty is, even though I have tried to optimize code so that it would jump over various "definitely not filling conditions" matrices, solving my problem would still take years. This is because, for example in one variation of this problem I have:
8 Indians, 10 Chinese, 15 Mexicans, 16 Americans and 22 canadians.
Matrix will be sized 5 x 71 and there will be kind a lot of matrices to check through :D

Different approach might just be needed. I hope some of you will open this to me and I will generously reward you!

Comment: Do you count all the people of one nationality as indistinguishable, so just the total number counts, or is each person to be counted distinctly?

Answer (score 1):

Several thoughts, not quite hints but too long for a comment.

I suspect that there is no neat combinatorial argument that leads to a formula. Partitions are hard. You probably do need an algorithm. If this is an assignment rather than a problem you just invented that's likely.

Study the problem first when there are just two nationalities, then three. You may find a recursive solution. That is likely to be better than building the matrices - you know that doesn't scale.

One way to restate the problem is to note that you must avoid homogeneous subsets of size $2$ or more.

Answer (score 0):

Your letters are awkward, lets just call them a,b,c,d,e for now.
Then you have these unique groups

5) 
a, b, c, d, e

10) 
ab, ac, ad, ae, 
bc, bd, be, 
cd, ce
de

10) 
abc, abd, abe, 
acd, ace, 
ade,
bcd, bce
bde, 
cde

5) 
abcd, 
abce, 
abde, 
acde, 
bcde

1) abcde

So I count 31, which makes sense as 2^5-1
with - - - - - being #32.

I'm sure you can see the pattern used here.

Comment: I think you have misread the question. One possible subgroup is aab. If there are $3$ a's and $2$ b's there are $6$ groups of this type. These can be combined (in many ways) with the ways to distribute all the other people.

Comment: I did misread that. So you could have aab,aac, aad, aae,  aaab, aaac, aaad, aaae, aaaab, aaaac, aaaad, aaaae, abb, acc, add, aee, abcc, abdd, abee , etc.  Yes, that does make for many more possibilities.